# casperjs/phantomjs doesn't exit/goes into loop on casper.on('error', ... ) event

Tags: javascript, error-handling, casperjs, exit

Anyways, I'm getting started with casperjs, and I want to handle error events using the casper.on('error', ...). I'm on windows 7, 64-bit

Problem is that when doing this, and when an error is triggered, casperjs/phantomjs goes into a loop and doesn't process the exit/die.

Here's the sample code: (I intentionally comment out the 'var keywords' to test it out):

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start();
casper.then(function () {
    casper.echo('breaking down keywords');
    //var keywords = []; //comment out to test for error handling
    keywords.push('hello world');

    casper.echo('finished');
});

casper.on('error', function (msg, backtrace) {
    this.echo("=========================");
    this.echo("ERROR:");
    this.echo(msg);
    this.echo(backtrace);
    this.echo("=========================");
    this.die("die");


});

casper.run();
```

Here's an image:
http://prntscr.com/71aiuu

that infinite loop goes on and on and fills the console. I thought that the simple 'casper/this.die' will do its thing.

I also looked at the other issues like [phantomjs exit() doesn't terminate the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897493/phantomjs-exit-doesnt-terminate-the-process?rq=1), but I only have intel hd graphics.

Any recommendations on what I should do?