# Selenium Webdriver : Unable to find executable for: taskkill

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Hello Guys I am running a simple code in selenium webdriver but I am getting error in console "Unable to find executable for: taskkill". And "Firefox has stop working" error in firefox. Can someone suggest me what should I do ?

Comment: Can you please share the code and more details on language. Complete error details aswell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver RuntimeException:Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it: Unable to find executable for: taskkill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776502/selenium-webdriver-runtimeexceptionprocess-refused-to-die-after-10-seconds-and)

Comment: What should be the solution to resolve this fresh window unable to open using webdriver it gives popup message firefox has stopped working..

public class amex {
 
 @Test
 
 public void amexHome()
 {
  WebDriver amex = new FirefoxDriver();
  amex.manage().window().maximize();
  
  amex.get("http://fedev.teleperformanceusa.com/AmEx/AmexCWCInbound/Test.htm");
  
  Select GenID = new Select(amex.findElement(By.id("accountNum")));
  GenID.selectByValue("371707859061005");
  amex.findElement(By.id("btnTest")).click();

  
 }

}

Comment: When I am running program as Java Application I am getting error message in console as "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."