# Selenium Web driver exception "Unable to find executable for: taskkill "

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

when I run the (driver.quit), it opens the firefox browser and quit it as expected but error is  given as "`Unable to find executable for: taskkill"`.
I set the environment variable PATH as "C:\Windows\System32" and run the test. But I still getting this error.

I am using Selenium-java-2.48.2.jar and Firefox 42.0

```
public void closeBrowser(){
        try{            
            driver.quit();          
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: try downgrading your firefox it might work,

Comment: have you restart you IDE after setting up the path ?

Comment: in selenium changelog you will find latest support is available only till FF41.0.2

Comment: @MrunalGosar I tried with the FF41.0.2 but still getting this error.

Comment: @kushanchathuranga Not sure why but same thing is working absolutely fine here with FF41.0.2 and WD 2.48.2..can u print the whole stacktrace here..lets see if we are able to find anything in that

Comment: @MrunalGosar I have share the screen shots for the whole stacktrace. Please refer the bellow link and share your thoughts. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5QNAucEkHx5LTlsYmdLdl9xaWM&usp=sharing

Comment: @kushanchathuranga..I think you have already closed browser and then you are calling quit method.. I would suggest you to try simple code snippet and see if this happens..also there is some known issue with testng 6.10. downgrade one version

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `driver.close()` instead `driver.quit()`. To understnad difference between them please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit).