# How to auto exit browser when timeout in selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want browser auto exit browser when timeout.

I was debugging it show correct in my mind. But when to run the application, I don't know it does not exit browser after `waiting_timeout` seconds.

My code like:

```
int waiting_timeout = 60;
_tmExcute = DateTime.Now;
// Do any thing
if ((DateTime.Now - _tmExcute).TotalSeconds > waiting_timeout)
{
    ExitALL();      // exit browser.
}
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit. Look like you need to call driver.quit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [driver.quit()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit--), this will quit the driver and close every associated window.

```
if ((DateTime.Now - _tmExcute).TotalSeconds > waiting_timeout)
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

If you have only one window open `driver.close()` will work also.

Answer (score 0):

On timeout, Selenium usually throws an exception. So your expression `((DateTime.Now - _tmExcute).TotalSeconds > waiting_timeout)` will never be `false`. You should use `try ... catch` instead.

Although it's better, if you use a test framework, to place the WebDriver shutdown in your `[TestCleanup]` or `[TearDown]`. Then you don't have to explicitly take care of the exceptions time and time again.