# python selenium driver.quit() inside except block

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exception

My application is such that if it throws an exception I want the driver to close, I tried the following code but it is throwing  exception .

My code:
where url is the url I want to open

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
try:
   driver.get(url)

except:

   driver.quit()
```

It is closing the driver but throwing an exception. How should I fix this?

This  is my stacktrace

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/folderpath", line 47, in <module>
    driver.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 505, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 425, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Show us your stacktrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `driver.close()` instead. In the example below there's no stacktrace displayed, the exception is caught and the driver/firefox window closes gracefully.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    raise WebDriverException
except WebDriverException:
    driver.close()
```

or even better practice - close your driver within a finally block:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    raise WebDriverException
except WebDriverException:
    'Handle your exception here'
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Well, as a popular discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266450/248616, it's better to call driver.quit() than driver.close() - one reason is that .quit() includes .close() call

Answer (score 6):

After numerous requests `webdriver` has finally been updated to implement the [context manager interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html). As of May, 2018 you can do:

```py
    with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev")
        raise WebDriverException
```

The context manager will take care of gracefully quitting and cleaning up. If you get an error then make sure you have the latest selenium module by running `pip install -U selenium`.

The corresponding pull request: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/5919.