# Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it: run time exception is throwing if using driver.quit()

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to close both Parent and child window.

So i am using 
driver.quit();

Its closing both windows properly but throwing the following exception
Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it: Unable to find executable for: taskkill

I tried with setting the path but the path is also correct.  Please suggest to avoid this exception

Answer (score 0):

Using `driver.close()` to close both windows , should avoid this exception. You can also use `driver.quit()` afterwards to exit the webdriver session. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit) is the difference between `quit` `close` and `dispose`

Answer (score 0):

Question: -See if you are getting the problem- Process refused to die after 10 seconds and couldn't task Kill it runtime exception in TestNG framework:

Answer: - I solve the problem by finding that sometimes your remote TestNG version and testng version in eclipse ide mismatches i.e [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.2 so you reinstall testng in eclipse ide after uninstalling and find out where you store your old version testng my remote testng is 7.4.0 and testng installed is 6.8.2 version so, I deleted the 6.8.2 folder and reinstalled latest version of testng which matches remote testng 7.4.0.....so after running my code I found this---[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0 and my code will pass.

In shorts, remote TestNG version and TestNG version in eclipse ide should be same.
This is how I get rid of this problem.
-----Thank you------

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).