# Getting error while running my first selenium code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I just started learning Selenium.

This is my code:

```
package sele;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();         
        driver.close();
        }
    }
```

This is the exception:

> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
>       at sele.Abc.main(Abc.java:10)

Comment: Please read: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can't say anything else about this than: you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: If you added Abc.java we can hazard a guess of whats happening...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is the same in java but in C# you use:

```
driver.Quit();
```

at the end of your code. Some use

```
driver.Dispose();
```

This will work as well.

[Look here for more Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit).