# how to close Python selenium webdriver window

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a python script that scraps data off from a website on an hourly basis. It is stored on the server at the moment and is working well as I am using task scheduler to schedule it to execute the script on an hourly basis.

I am using this code

```
driver.quit()
```

to quit the browser window

My problem to this that whenever I am not logging in to the server, it will start stacking up the webdriver window as somehow the driver.quit() function does not work when I am logging into the server. every morning when I came to work, I have tons of window to close from the server.

I tried to quit, close, dispose, but it doesn't help. What else I can try?

Comment: Does your code works with `quit()` when you execute manually with your console(terminal)?

Comment: yes it does. quit doesnt work when i am not logging in to the server

Comment: It honestly sounds like an exception is being raised before `driver.quit()` is executed. Are you sure your code is fully completing without any exceptions?

Answer (score 48):

In python using chromedriver, I quit Chrome processes with:

```
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 17):

For Python and chromedriver I've found these two methods useful (mind the difference):

`driver.close()` -  closes the browser active window.

`driver.quit()` -  closes all browser windows and ends driver's session/process.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still finding this question relevant in 2021 (heck it is for me!).

For me `driver.quit()` definitely was the right method. The main issue was tests not being cleaned up properly, meaning `driver.quit()` was never called.

- Make sure you run cleanup steps regardless of if the test crashes. e.g. in `unittest` use the `tearDown` or `tearDownClass` methods (setup the driver in `setUp`.
- If you can't do that wrap whatever you're doing with the `driver` object in a try / catch and do the `driver.quit()` in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 2):

Could'nt you scrape in headless mode? (example for chrome)

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.headless = True
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.create_options()
```

Comment: Yes, but you still need to close. I'm actually here because I just realized this - I have scripts running headless firefox and the headless processes stay open, innocently loitering at first and eventually tanking your system under the oppressive weight of their legion.

Comment: Yes, true, but difficult to see what's wrong without his code.

Answer (score 0):

I use linux command to close all. Here're two commands I ran after all scraping job is done:

- pkill firefox
- pkill Xcfb

Answer (score 0):

You can close browser by calling JavaScript close methods like so.

```
driver.execute_script("window.close();")
```

Answer (score -4):

I think `webDriver.Dispose()` should work, It closes all browser windows. Here is a [SO post about the 3 different ways to close a webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266450/6912791).

Comment: In python, all you get is `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Dispose'`