# Chrome webdriver - Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, background, webdriver, taskmanager

When I'm done with automating, the chrome webdriver stays running in the background, is there anyway to automatically close it without the need of doing it via task manager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to close Python selenium webdriver window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591175/how-to-close-python-selenium-webdriver-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.close()` => It will shut the focused browser window.

`driver.quit()` => It will shut all opened browser window and terminates the WebDriver session.

Comment: where you want to close your window

Comment: But i already don't know where to write that's why i'm asking, i automate in vs code, then i don't know where to write this command to kill the webdriver task?

Comment: after all the tasks are completed, at the ending of your code

Comment: the linter gives me a redline under the driver word and it doesn't execute..

Comment: driver should be what you defined webdriver.Chrome() or Firefox() to