# When I use selenium webdriver.Chrome().close(), does it will switch to the window before?

Tags: screen-scraping, selenium

here is my code:

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.switch_to.window(self.chrome.window_handles[1])
dosth...
chrome.close()
chrome.switch_to.window(self.chrome.window_handles[0])#
```

I want to know when I use the method 'close', do I need the last code line to switch to the window before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.close()` closed the `webdriver` object. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591175/how-to-close-python-selenium-webdriver-window).

So,

```py
chrome.close()
chrome.switch_to.window(self.chrome.window_handles[0])
```

is wrong. As this will close the `webdriver`. Instead:

```py
chrome.switch_to.window(self.chrome.window_handles[0])
chrome.close()
```

is correct.