# How to address the error The file geckodriver.exe is being used by another process using Firefox and Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to run my test in Chrome and Firefox using selenium c#.
The problem is, when install the Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver to be able to run the test on Firefox browser it breaks my code and I'm not able to run the test in chrome or Firefox.
Any idea?

I've installed

- Selenium.WebDriver
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver
- Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver
- Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver

Error:

```
The file geckodriver.exe is being used by another process
```

Another error:

```
The file is locked by geckodriver
```

Code trials:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;

    internal class Program
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            //IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            }
            [SetUp] //method to initialize page with windows maximized. 
            public void Initialize()
            {
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.demo.bnz.co.nz/client/");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
            }
public void Payees()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //verify if page is loaded 
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='left']/div[1]/div/button"));//menu            
            element.Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='left']/div[1]/div/div[3]/section/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[3]/a")).Click(); //payes
        }
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stacktrace.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Says"The file geckodriver.exe is being used by another process"

Comment: Another error: "The file is locked by geckodriver"

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
"The file geckodriver.exe is being used by another process
```

and

```
The file is locked by geckodriver
```

...implies that there are residual [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) processes of the previous test execution occupying your system's memory.

Unless those dangling [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) processes are removed your program would be unable to start a new [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220) service.

To kill the residual processes you can use the following code block:

- Using *`GetProcessesByName()`*:

  ```
  foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("geckodriver"))
  {
      process.Kill();
  }
  ```
- Using *`Process.GetProcesses()`* filtering out the required processes:

  ```
  var chromeDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
      Where(pr => pr.ProcessName == "chromedriver"); // without .exe

  foreach (var process in chromeDriverProcesses)
  {
     process.Kill();
  }
  ```

---

### Ideal Solution

Ideally to get rid of this redundant process always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-junit-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-cal/48003289#48003289)
- [Selenium initiated ChromeDriver keeps running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445545/selenium-initiated-chromedriver-keeps-running-in-background/43452691#43452691)
- [How to quit all the Firefox processes which gets initiated through GeckoDriver and Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830622/how-to-quit-all-the-firefox-processes-which-gets-initiated-through-geckodriver-a/58833151#58833151)

Comment: Where in my code should I use this Method?

Comment: @Yorda Check the added details and references.

Comment: I have teardown in my code, but was commented. I'll uncheck that. Thanks