# PhantomJS web driver stays in memory

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I am instantiating the PhantomJSDriver in C# with this code:

```
Driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

And cleaning it up with this:

```
Driver.Dispose();
Driver = null;
```

Should the process exit or stay in memory? If it is supposed to stay in memory, visible in the Windows 7 task manager, can I kill it programmatically? Should I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between webdriver.Dispose(), .Close() and .Quit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering straight, `Driver.Dispose();` shouldn't be used to clean up the `WebDriver` instance. For a proper cleanup we must be using `Driver.Quit();`.

1. `Driver.Dispose();`: I think got deprecated.
2. `Driver.Close();`: It is used to close the current page or the browser (if it is the only page/tab) which is having the focus.
3. `Driver.Quit();`: It is used to call the `/shutdown endpoint` and subsequently the web driver instance is destroyed completely closing all the pages/tabs/windows.

Hence calling the **`Driver.Quit()`** method is the only way to guarantee that sessions are properly terminated.

In this [`discussion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit) you can find a detailed analysis on `Driver.Dispose();`, `Driver.Close();` and `Driver.Quit();`