# Selenium: Getting chrome didn't shut down correctly

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the chrome didn't shut down correctly error message when I reopen a chrome browser in my selenium framework.

In the framework I'm opening the browser instance at the beginning for each of my test case using the below code

```
if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            try {                               
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", curProj+"\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
                options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
                //options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/xw20/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
                options.addArguments(chromeProfile);
                webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                logger.info("getWebDriver - Setting webdriver.chrome.driver system property as: " + System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                logger.error("The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property. ",e.fillInStackTrace());
                throw new IllegalStateException("The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property.");
            }
```

and closing at the end using the below code

```
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

But when I open a browser for the second test case I'm getting "chrome didn't shut down correctly" popup message.

I tried updating the below in the Preferences file of chrome profile but no luck

```
exit_type:Crashed
exited_cleanly:true
```

Configuration :

**Chrome Version:** Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (32-bit)

**Selenium Version:** 3.11.0

Answer (score 2):

As per your code it would be tough to analyze the reason behind the error **chrome didn't shut down correctly** without knowing your framework structure. Perhaps a more details about how *code block* was invoked (i.e. *main()* or *TestNG*) would have helped us.

Having said that there still seems some more factors to look at as follows :

- If you are using an existing *Chrome Profile* through **user-data-dir** ideally you should avoid the switches **setExperimentalOption** and **addArguments** for customization as those should be set within the respective *Chrome Profile*.
- As you are using an existing *Chrome Profile* through **user-data-dir** as per the documentation [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) the *path* should point the *profile directory* as follows :

  ```
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/xw20/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2")
  ```
- Here you can find a detailed discussion at [**How to open a Chrome Profile through Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195)
- Avoid using `driver.close();` and always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Here you can find a detailed discussion at [**PhantomJS web driver stays in memory**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* version to current ***Chrome v65.x*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set exit_type:Normal, I'm currently doing that before the test start, and or after the test ends and it Works.
on C#

```
 public static void FixChromeSingleProfile(string dataDir)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(dataDir, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        if (jsonDe.profile.exit_type != "Normal")
        {
            jsonDe.profile.exit_type = "Normal";
            string r = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDe);

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dataDir, false);
            sw.Write(r);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is in Python and works 100% but you should be able to implement this in Java as well. I just call the `close_windows` function every time I am finished using Selenium.

```
def close_windows():

    windows = driver.window_handles

    for w in windows:
        driver.switch_to.window(w)
        driver.close()

    driver.quit()

close_windows()
```