# MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, urllib3

I have one question:I want to test "select" and "input".can I write it like the code below:
original code:

```
 12 class Sinaselecttest(unittest.TestCase):
 13 
 14     def setUp(self):
 15         binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/local/firefox/firefox')
 16         self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
 17 
 18     def test_select_in_sina(self):
 19         driver = self.driver
 20         driver.get("https://www.sina.com.cn/")
 21         try:
 22             WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(
 23                 ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/form/div[3]/input"))
 24             )
 25         finally:
 26             driver.quit()
 # #测试select功能
 27         select=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='slt_01']")).select_by_value("微博")
 28         element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/form/div[3]/input")
 29         element.send_keys("杨幂")
 30         driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/form/input").click()
 31         driver.implicitly_wait(5)

 32    def tearDown(self):
 33        self.driver.close()
```

I want to test Selenium "select" function.so I choose sina website to select one option and input text in textarea.then search it .but when I run this test,it has error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_sina_select.py", line 32, in tearDown
        self.driver.close()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 688, in close
        self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
        response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 376, in execute
        return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 399, in _request
        resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
        **urlopen_kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 81, in request_encode_url
        return self.urlopen(method, url, **urlopen_kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 247, in urlopen
        response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 617, in urlopen
        release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 617, in urlopen
        release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 617, in urlopen
        release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 271, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51379): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2e64d2a1-3c7f-4221-96fe-9d0b1c102195/window (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 72.106s
```

who can tell me why?thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max retries exceeded with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url)

Comment: @郑佳妮 Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: @DebanjanB the question have been update.

Comment: @Infern0,Ok,I will look it.thank you.

Comment: what did you set implicitly_wait to ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error message...

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51379): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2e64d2a1-3c7f-4221-96fe-9d0b1c102195/window (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))
```

...implies that the call to **`self.driver.close()`** method failed raising **MaxRetryError**.

---

A couple of things:

- First and foremost as per the discussion [max-retries-exceeded exceptions are confusing](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198) the *traceback* is somewhat misleading. Requests wraps the exception for the users convenience. The original exception is part of the message displayed.
- Requests never retries (it sets the `retries=0` for urllib3's `HTTPConnectionPool`), so the error would have been much more canonical without the **MaxRetryError** and **HTTPConnectionPool** keywords. So an ideal *Traceback* would have been:

  ```
    ConnectionError(<class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 1111] Connection refused)
  ```
- But again @sigmavirus24 in his [comment](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198#issuecomment-16089745) mentioned *...wrapping these exceptions make for a great API but a poor debugging experience...*
- Moving forward the plan was to *traverse as far downwards as possible to the lowest level exception and use that instead.*
- Finally this issue was fixed by rewording some exceptions which has nothing to do with the actual connection refused error.

---

### Solution

Even before `self.driver.close()` within `tearDown(self)` is invoked, the *try{}* block within `test_select_in_sina(self)` includes *finally{}* where you have invoked `driver.quit()`which is used to call the */shutdown* endpoint and subsequently the web driver & the client instances are destroyed completely closing all the pages/tabs/windows. Hence no more connection exists.

> You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:
>
> - [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
> - [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling
>   driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

In such a situation when you invoke `self.driver.close()` the [python](/questions/tagged/python) client is unable to locate any active connection to initiate a clousure. Hence you see the error.

So a simple solution would be to remove the line `driver.quit()` i.e. remove the `finally` block.

---

### tl; dr

As per the *Release Notes* of **Selenium 3.14.1**:

```
* Fix ability to set timeout for urllib3 (#6286)
```

The *Merge* is: [repair urllib3 can't set timeout!](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6286)

---

### Conclusion

Once you upgrade to **Selenium 3.14.1** you will be able to set the timeout and see canonical *Tracebacks* and would be able to take required action.

---

### References

A couple of relevent references:

- [Adding max_retries as an argument](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1219)
- [Removed the bundled charade and urllib3.](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1812)
- [Third party libraries committed verbatim](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1384)

Comment: ,I thought "select" function error ,It turned out to be timeout reason.Thans for you,I will try to uprade my Selenium and modify my "select".

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. The solution was to change the owner of the folder with a script recursively. In my case the folder had `root:root` owner:group and I needed to change it to `ubuntu:ubuntu`.

**Solution:** `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /path-to-your-folder`

Answer (score 0):

Use Try and catch block to find exceptions

```
try:
  r = requests.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
  #Message
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
  #Message
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
  #Message
raise SystemExit(e)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.