# Script Suddenly Stops Crawling Without Error or Exception

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, geckodriver, urllib3

I'm not sure why, but my script always stops crawling once it hits [page 9](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-3_4bc8_page_9?gb_f_c2xvdC0z=discountRanges:10-25%252C25-50%252C50-70%252C70-,page:9,sortOrder:BY_DISCOUNT_DESCENDING,dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=5ZFYV9FYXCK98KYPJXMC&ie=UTF8). There are no errors, exceptions, or warnings, so I'm kind of at a loss.

Can somebody help me out?

P.S. [Here is the full script in case anybody wants to test it for themselves!](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/gBLPPr)

```
def initiate_crawl():
    def refresh_page(url):
        ff = create_webdriver_instance()
        ff.get(url)
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="FilterItemView_sortOrder_dropdown"]/div/span[2]/span/span/span/span').click()
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "Discount - High to Low")]').click()
        items = WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]'))
        )
        print(len(items))
        for count, item in enumerate(items):
            slashed_price = item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@class, "a-text-strike")]')
            active_deals = item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[contains(text(), "Add to Cart")]')
            if len(slashed_price) > 0 and len(active_deals) > 0:
                product_title = item.find_element(By.ID, 'dealTitle').text
                if product_title not in already_scraped_product_titles:
                    already_scraped_product_titles.append(product_title)
                    url = ff.current_url
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                    break
            if count+1 is len(items):
                try:
                    next_button = WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(
                        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→'), 'Next→')
                    )
                    ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→').click()
                    url = ff.current_url
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                except Exception as error:
                    print(error)
                    ff.quit()

    refresh_page('https://www.amazon.ca/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-3_4bc8_dct_10-?gb_f_c2xvdC0z=sortOrder:BY_SCORE,discountRanges:10-25%252C25-50%252C50-70%252C70-&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=CQ7KBNXT36G95190QJB1&ie=UTF8')

initiate_crawl()
```

Printing the length of `items` invokes some strange behaviour too. Instead of it always returning 32, which would correspond to the number of items on each page, it prints `32` for the first page, `64` for the second, `96` for the third, so on and so forth. I fixed this by using `//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]/div[contains(@class, "dealContainer")]` instead of `//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]` as the XPath for the `items` variable. I'm hoping this is the reason why it runs into issues on page 9. I'm running tests right now. **Update:** It is now scraping page 10 and beyond, so the issue is resolved.

Comment: Did you monitored the crawling process? Are there still buttons like ‘More’ in 9th page?

Comment: @jihan1008 everything is monitored. ive checked the xpath, everything, nothing seems to be broken

Comment: Can you check with different browser versions

Comment: @NarendraR i'm not exactly sure how to do that? how can i do that?

Comment: I couldn't get your script to run but it seems likely that at some point you're getting items of length 0 and so the enumeration loop isn't happening. Try printing the length of items before the loop and see what happens before the code ends.

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell good idea! i'm at the pt where i believe it must be somewhere else in the script. i've currently set a bunch of `time.sleep(n)`s and running a test with that. after that i'll printing the length! thanks for the input <3

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell youd think tho that it would throw an error if `items` failed to find anything. i mean, it ***should*** or ***would*** throw an error. worth exploring at this pt nonetheless

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell so i've noticed something super strange, instead of `len(items)` returning the number of items on each page, it'll return `32` for the first page, then `64` for the second page (33-64), `96` for the third (65-96), so on and so forth... how can this be happening?? wth

Comment: That is strange and not the behaviour I'd expect, but it may be a side effect of the way the site is coded. That could be what's causing the problem, but if so I imagine the problem would happen on page 2 already, so I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Good luck!

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell it must have something to do with the site since i `quit` the instance of the webdriver and then create another instance anew... man ive tested much longer scripts on amazon and it seems like theyve done almost everything in their power to try and prevent scraping/ddosing stuff. unfortunate

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell so i changed up my script a bit and duplicated the `if count+1...` statement on the same level as the `if product_title not in` statement and got the following error: `HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=58992): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/e8beed9b-4faa-4e91-a659-56761cb604d7/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000022D31378A58>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))` which is strange since i never received [cont.]

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell ...an error like this before. obvs it indicates that Amazon is actively refusing my connection on that page. not sure why only the additional `if` statement would invoke that

Answer (score 6):

As per your [10<sup>th</sup> revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52692120/10) of this question the error message...

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=58992): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/e8beed9b-4faa-4e91-a659-56761cb604d7/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000022D31378A58>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

...implies that the `get()` method failed raising **HTTPConnectionPool** error with a message **Max retries exceeded**.

A couple of things:

- As per the discussion [max-retries-exceeded exceptions are confusing](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198) the *traceback* is somewhat misleading. Requests wraps the exception for the users convenience. The original exception is part of the message displayed.
- Requests never retries (it sets the `retries=0` for urllib3's `HTTPConnectionPool`), so the error would have been much more canonical without the **MaxRetryError** and **HTTPConnectionPool** keywords. So an ideal *Traceback* would have been:

  ```
    NewConnectionError(<class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
  ```
- You will find a detailed explaination in [MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686968/maxretryerror-httpconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded-caused-by-protocolerror)

### Solution

As per the *Release Notes* of **Selenium 3.14.1**:

```
* Fix ability to set timeout for urllib3 (#6286)
```

The *Merge* is: [repair urllib3 can't set timeout!](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6286)

### Conclusion

Once you upgrade to **Selenium 3.14.1** you will be able to set the timeout and see canonical *Tracebacks* and would be able to take required action.

### References

A couple of relevent references:

- [Adding max_retries as an argument](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1219)
- [Removed the bundled charade and urllib3.](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1812)
- [Third party libraries committed verbatim](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1384)

---

### This usecase

I have taken your full script from [codepen.io - A PEN BY Anthony](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/gBLPPr). I had to make a few tweaks to your existing code as follows:

- As you have used:

  ```
    ua_string = random.choice(ua_strings)
  ```

You have to mandatorily import `random` as:

```
    import random
```

- You have created the variable **next_button** but haven't used it. I have clubbed up the following four lines:

  ```
    next_button = WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(
                    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→'), 'Next→')
                )
    ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→').click()
  ```

  As:

  ```
    WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→'), 'Next→'))
    ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→').click()
  ```
- Your modified code block will be:

  ```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import time
    import random


    """ Set Global Variables
    """
    ua_strings = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36']
    already_scraped_product_titles = []



    """ Create Instances of WebDriver
    """
    def create_webdriver_instance():
        ua_string = random.choice(ua_strings)
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', ua_string)
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        return webdriver.Firefox(profile)



    """ Construct List of UA Strings
    """
    def fetch_ua_strings():
        ff = create_webdriver_instance()
        ff.get('https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/')
        ua_strings_ff_eles = ff.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="useragent"]')
        for ua_string in ua_strings_ff_eles:
            if 'mobile' not in ua_string.text and 'Trident' not in ua_string.text:
                ua_strings.append(ua_string.text)
        ff.quit()



    """ Log in to Amazon to Use SiteStripe in order to Generate Affiliate Links
    """
    def log_in(ff):
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@id="nav-link-yourAccount"] | //a[@id="nav-link-accountList"]').click()
        ff.find_element(By.ID, 'ap_email').send_keys('anthony_falez@hotmail.com')
        ff.find_element(By.ID, 'continue').click()
        ff.find_element(By.ID, 'ap_password').send_keys('lo0kyLoOkYig0t4h')
        ff.find_element(By.NAME, 'rememberMe').click()
        ff.find_element(By.ID, 'signInSubmit').click()



    """ Build Lists of Product Page URLs
    """
    def initiate_crawl():
        def refresh_page(url):
        ff = create_webdriver_instance()
        ff.get(url)
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="FilterItemView_sortOrder_dropdown"]/div/span[2]/span/span/span/span').click()
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "Discount - High to Low")]').click()
        items = WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]'))
        )
        for count, item in enumerate(items):
            slashed_price = item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@class, "a-text-strike")]')
            active_deals = item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[contains(text(), "Add to Cart")]')
            # For Groups of Items on Sale
            # active_deals = //*[contains(text(), "Add to Cart") or contains(text(), "View Deal")]
            if len(slashed_price) > 0 and len(active_deals) > 0:
                product_title = item.find_element(By.ID, 'dealTitle').text
                if product_title not in already_scraped_product_titles:
                    already_scraped_product_titles.append(product_title)
                    url = ff.current_url
                    # Scrape Details of Each Deal
                    #extract(ff, item.find_element(By.ID, 'dealImage').get_attribute('href'))
                    print(product_title[:10])
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                    break
            if count+1 is len(items):
                try:
                    print('')
                    print('new page')
                    WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→'), 'Next→'))
                    ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→').click()
                    time.sleep(10)
                    url = ff.current_url
                    print(url)
                    print('')
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                except Exception as error:
                    """
                    ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pagination-both-004143081429407891"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()
                    url = ff.current_url
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                    """
                    print('cannot find ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Next?")')
                    print('Because of... {}'.format(error))
                    ff.quit()

        refresh_page('https://www.amazon.ca/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-3_4bc8_dct_10-?gb_f_c2xvdC0z=sortOrder:BY_SCORE,discountRanges:10-25%252C25-50%252C50-70%252C70-&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=CQ7KBNXT36G95190QJB1&ie=UTF8')

    #def extract_info(ff, url):
    fetch_ua_strings()
    initiate_crawl()
  ```
- Console Output: With **Selenium v3.14.0** and **Firefox Quantum v62.0.3**, I can extract the following output on the console:

  ```
    J.Rosée Si
    B.Catcher 
    Bluetooth4
    FRAM G4164
    Major Crim
    20% off Oh
    True Blood
    Prime-Line
    Marathon 3
    True Blood
    B.Catcher 
    4 Film Fav
    True Blood
    Texture Pa
    Westinghou
    True Blood
    ThermoPro 
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ```

> **Note**: I could have *optimized* your code and performed the same *web scraping* operations initializing the *Firefox Browser Client* only **once** and traverse through various products and their details. But to preserve your ***logic*** and ***innovation*** I have suggested the minimal changes required to get you through.

Comment: That `HTTPConnectionPool` error in my question is an outlier. The script works perfectly fine until it suddenly stops on page 9 without an error or exception. The only reason I set but didn't use `next_button` is because I was trying to troubleshoot this, thought that might've had something to do with it, and never reset it. The question/issue here is **why does it stop crawling/scraping once it finishes page 9??**

Comment: oh maybe that was why i never reset it. `WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→'), 'Next→')).click()` returns a `bool object` which isn't clickable. you have an error in your code

Comment: @Anthony As per your observation I have made some small modifications in my solution. I could have _optimized_ your code and performed the same _web scrapping_ opening the _Firefox Browser Client_ only once and traversing through various products. But to preserve your _logic_ and _innovation_ I have suggested the minimal changes required to get you through. Can you please try the updated solution and let me know the status please?

Comment: i actually fixed the issue on my own a number of days ago. i had updated my question and just updated it again for the sake of clarity. yeah, there is a specific reason why i'm not traversing the website using a single instance, but instead creating multiple instances. though now that i think about it, creating new instances may not even be necessary with `ff.back()` functionality, but it's still certainly a lot more straight forward. i will give your answer a read when i get some free time! thanks for trying to solve my issue <3

Answer (score 0):

I slightly adjusted the code and it seems to work. Changes:

`import random` statement because it is used and would not run without it.

Inside `product_title` loop these lines are removed:

`ff.quit()`, `refresh_page(url)` and `break`

The `ff.quit()` statement would cause a fatal (connection) error causing the script to break.

Also `is` changed to `==` for `if count + 1 == len(item):`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import random



""" Set Global Variables
"""
ua_strings = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36']
already_scraped_product_titles = []



""" Create Instances of WebDriver
"""
def create_webdriver_instance():
    ua_string = random.choice(ua_strings)
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', ua_string)
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    return webdriver.Firefox(profile)

""" Construct List of UA Strings
"""
def fetch_ua_strings():
    ff = create_webdriver_instance()
    ff.get('https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/')
    ua_strings_ff_eles = ff.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="useragent"]')
    for ua_string in ua_strings_ff_eles:
        if 'mobile' not in ua_string.text and 'Trident' not in ua_string.text:
            ua_strings.append(ua_string.text)
    ff.quit()

""" Build Lists of Product Page URLs
"""
def initiate_crawl():
    def refresh_page(url):
        ff = create_webdriver_instance()
        ff.get(url)
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="FilterItemView_sortOrder_dropdown"]/div/span[2]/span/span/span/span').click()
        ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "Discount - High to Low")]').click()
        items = WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]'))
        )
        print(items)
        for count, item in enumerate(items):
            slashed_price = item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@class, "a-text-strike")]')
            active_deals = item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[contains(text(), "Add to Cart")]')
            # For Groups of Items on Sale
            # active_deals = //*[contains(text(), "Add to Cart") or contains(text(), "View Deal")]
            if len(slashed_price) > 0 and len(active_deals) > 0:
                product_title = item.find_element(By.ID, 'dealTitle').text
                if product_title not in already_scraped_product_titles:
                    already_scraped_product_titles.append(product_title)
                    url = ff.current_url
                    # Scrape Details of Each Deal
                    #extract(ff, item.find_element(By.ID, 'dealImage').get_attribute('href'))
                    print(product_title[:10])
                    # This ff.quit()-line breaks connection which breaks things.:
                    #ff.quit()
                    # And why 
                    #refresh_page(url)
                    #break
            # 'is' tests for object equality; == tests for value equality:
            if count+1 == len(items):
                try:
                    print('')
                    print('new page')
                    next_button = WebDriverWait(ff, 15).until(
                        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→'), 'Next→')
                    )
                    ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Next→').click()                    
                    time.sleep(3)
                    url = ff.current_url
                    print(url)
                    print('')
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                except Exception as error:
                    """
                    ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pagination-both-004143081429407891"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()
                    url = ff.current_url
                    ff.quit()
                    refresh_page(url)
                    """
                    print('cannot find ff.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Next→")')
                    print('Because of... {}'.format(error))
                    ff.quit()

    refresh_page('https://www.amazon.ca/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-3_4bc8_dct_10-?gb_f_c2xvdC0z=sortOrder:BY_SCORE,discountRanges:10-25%252C25-50%252C50-70%252C70-&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=CQ7KBNXT36G95190QJB1&ie=UTF8')

#def extract_info(ff, url):
fetch_ua_strings()
initiate_crawl()
```