# Does test execution using selenium and webdriver through python have any affect on the network?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to use selenium at my workplace. I have read about proxies watching this video about gecko driver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-Jq9GrNVVc
I dont want to get in any problem using this. I just want to automate the processes, I have some experience in python and when I tried using selenium impressed me how easy can processess automate.

Comment: Is the question whether WebDriver will negatively affect the bandwidth available to other users of your corporate network? (The answer is: it depends on how much you're trying to download using it!)

Comment: I mean can cause any issue in the network running a webdriver using python selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, while your *Automation Suite* is in execution through *Selenium* the execution process is bound to consume and affect the **network** and **bandwidth**.

*Selenium* being a tool for *Web Automation* will access *Web Pages* and interact with the *WenElements* once the *Webpage* loads. Incase of unavailability of the required **bandwidth** you may see **HTTPConnectionPool** error with a message **Max retries exceeded**.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**HTTPConnectionPool** error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692120/script-suddenly-stops-crawling-without-error-or-exception/52738050#52738050)

In some cases you may even see the **Network Failure** error as follows:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//192.168.1.20/network.cgi&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E5%BB%BA%E7%AB%8B%E5%88%B0%20192.168.1.20%20%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8%E7%9A%84%E8%BF%9E%E6%8E%A5%E3%80%82
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure** error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900844/reached-error-page-aboutneterror-when-trying-to-navigate-to-other-tabs-if-ther/47902113#47902113)

### Solution

Ideally, your *Test Bed* should be:

- Configured with the required **network** and **bandwidth**.
- Configured with all the required **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration**.
- Configured with all the required **general computing hardware and software**.
- Configured with all the required *softwares*, *libraries* and *binaries*.
- *Test Execution* must be performed in a controled environment for optimized performance.

Comment: And can it cause issue on the network? for example can cause problem for my co-workers? I am not a programmer, i just want automate some processes in my work, so I dont want to use selenium for testing. Plus information: There is not python installed at my workplace, so I convert python script at home to exe file, and only the exe would run at my workplace.

Comment: Selenium web driver consumes the same brandwidth like the normal browsr, or not? I mean my work is often about copy-paste from a website, so if I manually load the website it also consumes bandwidth. So I worry about the network issue. I am not a programmer, so I didnt learnt about networks :/ .

Comment: @johndoel Answer for the questions within the first comment: 1. _can it cause issue on the network_ **No** it won't other than consuming bandwidth. 2. _convert python script at home to exe_ is different question altogether and you may like to raise a new question.

Comment: @johndoel Answer for the questions within the second comment: _Selenium web driver consumes the same brandwidth like the normal browsr_ is again a different qestion which needs research and you may like to raise a new question.