# MaxRetryError Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, httpconnection

I tried writing a simple script that checks the website every hour and sends me an email when it finds there's availability.

I figured doing this evey hour shouldn't trigger any problems but I'm getting the following error:

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=60745): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/900f45d6c8c800f2a8ebcf43daa05b69/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa42c261c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

This is my code:

```
import schedule
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from notification import *
#script i have to send an email (works fine)

PATH = "mypath"
# i have the path where there drivers are

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
# to not open the browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=PATH)

def get_stock():
    driver.get("website i'm trying to check")
    # access the website
    search = driver.find_element_by_name("add")
    # add is the name of the button i wanna check
    result = search.is_enabled()
    print(result)
    driver.quit()


schedule.every().hour.do(get_stock)
# run the get_stock function every hour

c = 0
# initialize the loop

while c == 0:
    schedule.run_pending()
    c = get_stock()
    # set the seed equal to the get_stock so that it stops once it becomes True
    time.sleep(1)
    print(get_stock())


email("Now there's a stock.")
#using my notification script to send the email
```

I'm a beginner so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you are being rate-limited by the website in question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get the error the moment I start running the code, and it should only try to access the website once every hour so I don't think so. But is there a way I could verify if that's the issue?

Answer (score 16):

This error message...

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=60745): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/900f45d6c8c800f2a8ebcf43daa05b69/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa42c261c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn/communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Root cause

The root cause of this error can be either of the following:

- This error may arise in case manually you are closing the *Browsing Context* when the driver have already initiated a lookout for element/elements.
- Incase you invoke any [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) [methods](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) once you have already invoked `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()`.
- There is also a possibility that the application you are trying to access is [throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336578/linkedin-api-throttle-limit/60555044#60555044) the requests from your system/machine/ip-address/network.
- The application have identified the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* as a bot and is [denying any access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191).

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) to synchronize the fast moving WebDriver along with the *Browsing Context*.
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686968/maxretryerror-httpconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded-caused-by-protocolerror/52701504#52701504)
- [urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=49951): Max retries exceeded with url with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617235/urllib3-exceptions-maxretryerror-httpconnectionpoolhost-127-0-0-1-port-4995)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond. Everything is up to date and I'm using a virtual environment with only the required dependencies. Could you say a bit more about the first two solutions you proposed? I tried looking them up but I'm still not sure I follow.

Comment: @justasking Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium).

Comment: Thank you! this help! I couldn't solve this error with neither GitHub copilot nor GPT4 :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move this line to the beginning of the get_stock () function

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=PATH)
```

it's probably too late, but it might come in handy