# How to address urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=58408): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I am trying to scrape a few pages of a website with selenium and use the results but when I run the function twice

```
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'
```

Error appears for the 2nd function call.
Here's my approach :

```
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN', None)
opts.add_argument("--headless")
opts.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="CHROME_DRIVER PATH", options=opts)

lst =[]
def search(st):
    for i in range(1,3):
        url = "https://gogoanime.so/anime-list.html?page=" + str(i)
        browser.get(url)
        req = browser.page_source
        sou = soup(req, "html.parser")
        title = sou.find('ul', class_ = "listing")
        title = title.find_all("li")
        for j in range(len(title)):
            lst.append(title[j].getText().lower()[1:])
    browser.quit()
    print(len(lst))
    
search("a")
search("a")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
272
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=58408): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/4b3cb270d1b5b867257dcb1cee49b368/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001D5B378FA60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error message...

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=58408): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/4b3cb270d1b5b867257dcb1cee49b368/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001D5B378FA60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

...implies that the failed to establish a new connection raising **MaxRetryError** as no connection could be made.

---

A couple of things:

- First and foremost as per the discussion [max-retries-exceeded exceptions are confusing](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198) the *traceback* is somewhat misleading. Requests wraps the exception for the users convenience. The original exception is part of the message displayed.
- Requests never retries (it sets the `retries=0` for urllib3's `HTTPConnectionPool`), so the error would have been much more canonical without the **MaxRetryError** and **HTTPConnectionPool** keywords. So an ideal *Traceback* would have been:

  ```
    ConnectionError(<class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 1111] Connection refused)
  ```

---

### Root Cause and Solution

Once you have initiated the webdriver and web client session, next within `def search(st)` you are invoking `get()` o access an *url* and in the subsequent lines you are also invoking `browser.quit()`  which is used to call the `/shutdown` endpoint and subsequently the webdriver & the web-client instances are destroyed completely closing all the pages/tabs/windows. Hence no more connection exists.

> You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:
>
> - [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
> - [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling
>   driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

In such a situation in the next iteration (due to the `for` loop) when `browser.get()` is invoked there are no active connections. hence you see the error.

So a simple solution would be to remove the line `browser.quit()` and invoke `browser.get(url)` within the same *browsing context*.

---

### Conclusion

Once you upgrade to **Selenium 3.14.1** you will be able to set the timeout and see canonical *Tracebacks* and would be able to take required action.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686968/maxretryerror-httpconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded-caused-by-protocolerror/52701504#52701504)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevent discussions:

- [Adding max_retries as an argument](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1219)
- [Removed the bundled charade and urllib3.](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1812)
- [Third party libraries committed verbatim](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1384)

Comment: This helped but the chromedriver process is impacting the memory. Shall I use `os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")`?  I am on a windows machine.

Comment: @SumitJaiswal In short, yes you need to do that but there are a couple of other factors to consider. Let me know if you are stuck.

Comment: Killing chromedriver whilst being in the `for` loop is a bad idea.  So I made a `kill()` function for  `os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")`. But invoking `search()` then `kill()` then `search()` again gives the same error. Is there a way to restart the chromedriver whenever I call `search()`

Comment: I think I fixed both problems by bringing the `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="CHROME_DRIVER PATH", options=opts)` inside the function and using `browser.quit()` at the end of it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Amazing answer, I simply missed a "return" in my function to be honest. But great effort, well written. Loved reading it.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The driver was asked to crawl the URL after being quit.
Make sure that you're not quitting the driver before getting the content.

**Solution**

Regarding your code, when executing `search("a")` , the driver retrieves the url, returns the content and after that it closes.

when `serach()` runs another time, the driver no longer exists so it is not able to proceed with the URL.

You need to remove the `browser.quit()` from the function and add it at the end of the script.

```
lst =[]
def search(st):
    for i in range(1,3):
        url = "https://gogoanime.so/anime-list.html?page=" + str(i)
        browser.get(url)
        req = browser.page_source
        sou = soup(req, "html.parser")
        title = sou.find('ul', class_ = "listing")
        title = title.find_all("li")
        for j in range(len(title)):
            lst.append(title[j].getText().lower()[1:])
    print(len(lst))
    
search("a")
search("a")
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Robot Framework.

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001ABA3190F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')).
```

This issue got fixed once I updated all the libraries to their latest version in Pycharm and also I selected `Intellibot@SeleniumLibrary.patched`