# Can we just run the chromedriver once with Selenium while repeat automation?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium to perform automation.
However, if I repeat automation, I have a lot of chromedrivers.

I want to solve this problem.
Can't you just run one chromedriver?

[image]

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the screenshot you have provided there seems to be presence of a couple of [Zombie ChromeDriver process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) within your system.

Answering straight, you can't work with initiating just one **ChromeDriver** process while *repeat automation* as you can not reconnect to the previous browsing session. You can find a detailed discussion in [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium/47862867#47862867)

You code trials would have given us more insights why the **ChromeDriver** processes are not getting cleaned up. As per best practices always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully as follows:

```
driver.quit() // Python
//or
driver.quit(); // Java
//
driver.Quit(); // DotNet
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)

Incase the **ChromeDriver** processes are still not destroyed and removed you may require to kill the processes from tasklist. You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

- Python Solution(**Cross Platform**):

  ```
  import os
  import psutil

  PROCNAME = "geckodriver" # or chromedriver or IEDriverServer
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
      # check whether the process name matches
      if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
          proc.kill()
  ```

Comment: The answer is factually incorrect - that processes are not zombie one (that's very hard to achieve in Windows, borderline impossible), but orphaned - functional processes which parent is no longer present. The next one is reconnecting to an existing driver - OP hasn't asked for it, and yet - it's not that it is not possible, on the contrary - it is quite easy to do so, and very useful for development purposes.

Comment: Finally, the `proc.name()` solution is hardly cross platform - the name in the sample is Linux one, Windows names have .exe in them. The `kill()` method sends sigterm, which the processes may handle the way it wants, being a zombie - if it was a zombie process in the first place, which it is not -  with no action at all.

Comment: furthermore, psutil requires an additional dependency

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're left with the *driver.exe processes is most probably because you are not explicitly closing them at the end of your tests run - calling the `quit()` method on the driver object in your chosen language.

That step is usually done in the object's destructor - if you're using object-oriented approach; a `finally` block if it's exception-handling; or the the program's/script's exit lines. Most high-level frameworks (Cucumber, TestNG, Robotframework, the plethora of unit testing in the different languages) have some kind of "tear-down" blocks which is usually used for this purpose.

---

Why is this happening?

When you start your automation, the OS starts the process for it; when you instantiate a webdriver object, it spawns a process for the browser's driver - the "chromedriver.exe" in your case. The next step is to open the browser instance - the "chrome.exe".

When your run finishes, the process for it is closed. But, if you have not explicitly called the `quit()` method - the browser's driver persists, "stays alive"; and is now an orphaned process (not to be mistaken with a zombie one, which is a totally different thing) - fully functional, yet - with no program to command it.

In fact, at this stage - having a working driver process and a browser, you can reconnect to it, and use in future runs. Check out how and why here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52003231/3446126

Answer (score 0):

I use a cleanup routine at the end of my tests to get rid of zombie processes, temp files, etc. (Windows, Java)

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
  
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
    
    
public class TestCleanup {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestCleanup.class.getName());


    public void removeTemporaryFiles() {
        try {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(getPropertyValue("java.io.tmpdir")));
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            logger.info("IOexception trying to clean the downloads directory: " + ioException.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void closeWebdriver() {
        webDriver.close();
    }

    public void killOperatingSystemSessions() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM \"chromedriver.exe\" /F");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            logger.info("Exception when shutting down chromedriver process: " + ioException.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```