# What is the exact purpose of Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am new to Selenium, TestNG and Selenium Grid. I got slightly confused about when exactly I need to use Selenium Grid. Below are my understandings on this. Just let me know if i am right :

1. Selenium Grid is **only** for running your tests remotely on another machine
2. If I need to run my tests parallelly in my local Machine, there is no need to use Grid. That can be achieved by using TestNG only
3. If I need to execute my test, parallelly on different remote machines, Then i have to use selenium Grid along with TestNG.

So what i understand is, **the purpose of Selenium grid is NOT parallel execution**. It is for remote execution. **Parallel execution is achieved via TestNG**. *It is not possible to do parallel execution by only using Grid*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty correct in your conclusion that *the purpose of Selenium Grid is to execute the tests remotely on remote machines*. The two main reasons to distribute your tests are:

- Reduce execution time of your *Test Suite*.
- To avoid memory (e.g. RAM) crunch on your localhost and you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

  - [Limit chrome headless CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811)
  - [Many process of Google Chrome (32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466)
  - [Selenium using too much RAM with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072731/selenium-using-too-much-ram-with-firefox/55075243#55075243)
  - [Is it possible to reduce memory RAM consumption when using Selenium GeckoDriver and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028375/is-it-possible-to-reduce-memory-ram-consumption-when-using-selenium-geckodriver/54040334#54040334)

---

### Remote WebDriver

As per the official documentation of [Remote WebDriver](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/):

> You can use WebDriver remotely the same way you would use it locally. The primary difference is that a remote WebDriver needs to be configured so that it can run your tests on a separate machine.

A remote WebDriver is composed of two parts: the server and the client. The client is the WebDriver test and the server is simply a Java servlet, which can be hosted in any modern JEE app server.

---

### Remote WebDriver server

The [Remote WebDriver server](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_server/) will always run on the machine with the browser you want to test. The server can be initiated either from the command line (or through code configuration).

---

### Remote WebDriver client

To run a [Remote WebDriver client](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/) you have to first connect to the RemoteWebDriver. We do this by pointing the URL to the address of the server running our tests.

---

### Steps in details

You need to follow the below mentioned steps:

- Start the *Selenium Grid Hub*:

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
  ```
- Logs generated:

  ```
  18:10:13.310 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
  18:10:13.618 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
  2020-01-02 18:10:14.605:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2136ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  18:10:15.504 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
  18:10:15.509 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register/
  18:10:15.510 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.125:4444/wd/hub
  ```
- Access the **Selenium Grid Console v.3.141.59** through the url `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`:

[image: SeleniumGridConsole]

- Start the *Selenium Grid Node*:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -port 7777 -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register
  ```
- Logs generated:

  ```
  18:33:55.959 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
  18:33:56.112 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 7777
  2020-01-02 18:33:56.584:INFO::main: Logging initialized @983ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  18:33:56.913 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
  18:33:57.029 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 7777
  18:33:57.029 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
  18:33:57.195 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
  18:33:57.734 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register
  18:33:57.856 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
  ```
- Access the **Selenium Grid Console v.3.141.59** again through the url `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` to view the registered node:

[image: SeleniumGridConsole_NodeRegistered]

Comment: For extra info: I used selenium grid to do some `repeated tasks` on a filtered website (on port 80 and 443) in my hell country Iran. My c# app using`RemoteWebDrive`, connects to local `Hub` and the local Hub connects to my external VPS  as my node & run the tasks freely.