# How to access folder or file on Remote Machine Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

Automation framework using Java/Selenium/Serenity and TC agent with Hub/Nodes solution. When we download file, it is visible in node user folder. When we try to check it using:

```
File fileDownloads = new File (System.getProperty("user.home"))
```

But instead of machine where file was downloaded we see files on TC agent, where the actual framework is build. How to see what is saved on remote nodes?
We need more than just see it was downloaded (can be done byt checking chrome//downloads tab) but also get that file and check content.

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595459/how-to-upload-a-file-by-transfering-the-file-from-the-local-machine-to-the-remot/62596057#62596057) help you?

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for, it is solving issue from using files from Local machine to remote, but in my case file is already on remote machine folder, but not visible to me.