# How to upload multiple files with Selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, zalenium

The method is worked fine when I run tests locally, but when tests are run with a Selenium grid or Zalenium the multiple upload method not works.

```
String path = "a.jpg";
String path1 = "b.jpg";
String path2 = "c.jpg";

element.sendKeys(path + "\n " + path1 + "\n " + path2);
```

Did anyone solve this issue?

Comment: What symptoms or exception of 'method not works' are you experiencing?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found :

Comment: please add the screen shot of the element when you manually upload multiple files

Comment: after manually uploading the files the input field is disappearing, so there is nothing to take a screenshot of, what exactly do you need?

Comment: @Norayr Sargsyan this should be quite easy to solve. Just debug your code to determine what file is not found.

Comment: The first element is not found, after the "\n", The RemoteWebDriver can not understand the "\n" as a changing to the new line

Comment: You need localFileDetector.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595459/how-to-upload-a-file-by-transfering-the-file-from-the-local-machine-to-the-remot

Comment: Added, the single file upload works fine

Comment: looks like the getLocalFile method returns a single File: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/LocalFileDetector.java  That would be an issue... not sure how to get the uploaded file's path... but maybe try getLocalFile() to see if it returns remote-end path for you after using send keys?  (element.getLocalFile()? and getAbsolutePath() )  If so, you could use sendKeys three different times... collect the paths, clear the field and then send keys without fileDetector.

Answer (score 0):

For handling files in remote driver you need to set FileDetector.
Below is the code to set the file Detector.

```
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), getDesiredCapabilties(Browser.REMOTE_WEBDRIVER));
remoteWebDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

Comment: I know about this solution, the question is not about that