# Python Selenium Remote Webdriver Upload File

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python 3.9 and selenium 4.6.0 on Chrome.  I have a script that needs to upload a file to an input, this works fine on local but fails when run on RemoteDriver.  The code I am using is

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@accept]").send_keys('path to file')`

When run on RemoteDriver the error returned is

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: unknown command: session/cddd71e067d7717481fb8a635103c643/se/file`

I've think it is due to this line in the remote_connection.py file in selenium

`Command.UPLOAD_FILE: ('POST', "/session/$sessionId/se/file")`

From the research I've done the 'se' in this case is a 'vendor_prefix' for selenium but I cannot figure out how to either configure the remote driver to use a vendor prefix or remove that from POST path that is being passed (short of pulling my own version of the code and maintaining that).

For other functional reasons I can't revert to selenium 3x (which is an option I've seen to correct this), nor can I set w3c to False.  Does anyone know how to work around this particular issue; either by getting send_keys to operate as expected in this situation or using another method to upload the file?  Thanks.

Comment: that'll be specific to a certain driver... for remote you need to use a localFileDetector, though.  Are you doing that?  (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595459/how-to-upload-a-file-by-transfering-the-file-from-the-local-machine-to-the-remot )  Also remember that only a Selenium grid would understand this command.. (I think it'll ignore the "vender_prefix".)

Comment: I think the 'only selenium grid will understand' might've answered my question.  We're using aws device farm and a home grown framework.
For what it's worth, I did try setting the local file detector but encountered the same issue

        `from selenium.webdriver.remote.file_detector import LocalFileDetector
        driver.file_detector = LocalFileDetector()`

Comment: so the framework has to know there's a file coming in as an upload, and then it sets the <input type="file"> value to it's own local path.