# Upload doesn't work in remote server: Unsupported Command Exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have a complicated Java/Selenium framework at my job and I am having a hard time uploading an image wit sendKeys() in a remote server. The code works locally, but not on our Selenoid server. I've done lots of research and found out this was [stemming](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10352#issuecomment-1034802256) from W3C standards but I'm assuming it is fixed now.

Here is a piece of our code:

```
protected void sendKeysUploadPhoto(By by, String path) {
        executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", driver.findElement(by));
        ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        try {
            driver.findElement(by).clear();
            driver.findElement(by).sendKeys(path);
        } catch (WebDriverException wex) {
            Logger.fail("WebDriver Exception: ", wex);
        }
    }
```

I get the following error for the sendKeys() step:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: unknown command: unknown command: session/efe1d404f94de0019443b240970829d1/se/file
```

Comment: I think you want ((RemoteWebElement)THE <INPUT> ELEMENT OF TYPE FILE).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());  Right now you're setting it on the driver.  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323024/while-using-selenium-grid-how-do-we-access-downloaded-file-in-node-machine-from/65323499#65323499

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it didn't work. Here's what I did: 

`executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", driver.findElement(by));`
`WebElement uploadFile = driver.findElement(by);`
`((RemoteWebElement)uploadFile).setFileDetector( new LocalFileDetector());`
`uploadFile.clear();`
`uploadFile.sendKeys(path);`

This returned the same exception.

Comment: Make sure the remote end is a grid.  I think only the grid would understand that command from the driver.

Comment: an alternative would be to upload the file to the docker image and then just send keys normally with the uploaded file's destination/path (inside docker).