# SessionNotCreatedException when I set se:downloadsEnabled capability

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I am getting this error message thrown

**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.**

when I set the capability to download files from the grid nodes.

If I comment out **options.setCapability("se:downloadsEnabled", "true")**  the browser launches with the session created.

```
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.setCapability("platformName", Platform.LINUX);                  
                options.setCapability("se:downloadsEnabled", true); // Works when commented             
                HashMap<String, Object> chromePref = new HashMap<>();               
                chromePref.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", Boolean.valueOf(true));
                chromePref.put("download.prompt_for_download", Boolean.valueOf(false));
                chromePref.put("safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled", oolean.valueOf(false));
                options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePref);             
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/"), options);

}
```

- Chrome browser:114.0
- Selenium: 4.9.0
- ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90

I'd appreciate any help from anyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### [***se:downloadsEnabled***](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/cli_options/#start-the-node-with-manage-downloads-enabled)

[se:downloadsEnabled](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/cli_options/#set-the-capability-at-the-test-level) is only in [**Grid**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648301/7429447) configuration which is used to set the capability at the test level as follows:

```
options.setCapability("se:downloadsEnabled", true);
```

`se:downloadsEnabled` when set to *`true`* within a Grid infrastructure will try to match a session request with `se:downloadsEnabled` against only those nodes which were started with `--enable-managed-downloads` set to `true`. If a session is matched, then the Node automatically sets the required capabilities to let the browser know, as to where should a file be downloaded.

Then only the Node will allow a user to:

- List all the files that were downloaded for a specific session
- Retrieve a specific file from the list of files.

However, the directory into which files were downloaded for a specific session gets automatically cleaned up when the session ends (or) timesout due to inactivity.

**Note**: Currently this capability is supported only on:

- Edge
- Firefox
- Chrome

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I set  **--enable-managed-downloads**  to **true** using docker-compose? 
I use docker-compose to start up my hub and node.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
In your `docker-compose.yml` file  under the environment, add

```
- SE_OPTS=--enable-managed-downloads true
```