# The find_elements () function in Selenium consumes a lot of RAM

Tags: python, selenium, memory-management, ram

**Description of the situation:**
It is a script that scrolls in a frame in order to extract the information.

```
<ul>

<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
...
</ul>
```

The list length of about 30 items, when scrolling, no new items are added `<li> </li>`, only updated. The structure of the DOM does not increase.

**Explaining the problem:**
When the script scrolls, it must extract all the elements of the `<li> </li>` for each iteration because they are renewed.

Here is the logic of scrolling and extracting elements.
The code I use:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div[data-tid=\"pane-list-viewport\"]').scrollHeight;")

all_msgs_loaded = False

while not all_msgs_loaded:

    li_elements: List[WebElement] = self._driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-tid='pane-item']")

    driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('li[data-tid=\"pane-item\"]').scrollIntoView();")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div[data-tid=\"pane-list-viewport\"]').scrollHeight;")
    if new_height == last_height:
        all_msgs_loaded = True
    last_height = new_height
```

For each iteration li_elements receives about 30 WebElements.
If i comment on the line with find_elements, the script works for hours without increasing the RAM consumption.
I mention that I do not save anything in runtime, that I don't have an increase in consumption elsewhere.

> Another way I used to get li_elements is through `self._driwer.execute_script ()`

Example:

```
li_elements = (self._driver.execute_script(
                 "return document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tid=\"pane-item\"]');",
                 WebDriverWait(self._edge_driver, 20).until(
                     EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-tid='pane-item']")))
```

By both methods I get the same result that I have, but the RAM increase is the same.
RAM grows indefinitely until TaskManager destroys the process on its own for security.

I analyzed the internal structure of these functions, but I did not find anything that could load the RAM.
Another modality would be `find_elements_by_css_selector ()`, but inside it is called `find_elements ()`.

I also tried different combinations with sleep (), but nothing helps, RAM does not decrease.

Can you please explain to me what is happening in reality, I do not understand why RAM consumption is increasing.

Can you tell me if there is another method of extracting the elements without consuming RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting just what you need instead of the full element:

```
lis = driver.execute_script("""
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tid="pane-item"]')].map(li => li.innerText)
""")
```

I can't tell what you're doing with them, but if you're adding elements to a big array, and there's enough of them, you will hit a RAM limit

Comment: Hello @pguardiario,  thanks for the reply. I tried a similar combination.  `li_elements = self._driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('li["
                                                        "data-tid=\"chat-pane-item\"] div["
                                                        "class*=\"ui-chat__item__message\"]')].map(div => "
                                                        "div.innerHTML);")`

Comment: Now I get the same result, but the RAM grows much slower, and much less than it was at the same time.
At the same datetime the RAM difference is about 600-700 MB.
Very strange how that changed things, but it's much better.

Comment: I need innerHTML here, because the internal structure is large and then I process it with BeautifulSoup4

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. If I could see the html I could guess what you need and make a suggestion that's more efficient than parsing html with beautiful soup

Comment: Also, you could just make sure that your object is getting garbage collected inside your while loop, which it should be, but I think you didn't share the full code.

Comment: Hello @pguardiario, I've done a lot of testing, but RAM is loading slowly. Here is the structure: https://prnt.sc/LDmA-U3Y2b_X Each element has a large structure, and everything is needed

Comment: Can garbage collector release li_elements at runtime? I found another option in the browser "Use hardware acceleration (if available)". This significantly reduced the consumption of RAM.

Comment: It won't get garbage collected if there's a reference to it in scope

Answer (score 0):

By any means [find_elements()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) method of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) shouldn't be consuming so much of RAM. Most possibly it's the *Browsing Context* e.g. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) which consumes more RAM while you [*scrollIntoView()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581830/7429447) incase the *`<li>`* items gets updated through [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) or [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Without any visibility in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) it would be difficult to predict the actual reason or any remediation. However, a similar [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54044149/7429447) suggests to use some waits interms of `time.sleep(n)`

Comment: Hello @undetected Selenium, thanks for the reply. In my case I use Microsoft Edge, if I comment on the line with `find_elements ()`, `scrollIntoView ()` works, but the RAM consumption does not increase at all, because the DOM structure does not increase, it is static. The `<ul>` list of items `<li>` is only updated from the server.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/l7fj8PFQsLOM , here is a screen from the <ul> List, at each scroll it is only updated from the server

Comment: _<ul> list of items <li> is only updated from the server_: Definately JavaScript/AJAX is in play.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But without `find_elements ()`, scrolling doesn't affect RAM at all.