# How to kill the WebDriver instance keeping the Web Browser open

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, webdriver

I am developing an automatic web unit test with Selenium WebDriver.
I know that I can use the `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` method to close the browser and to release the **chromedriver** from the memory after the test but it's not good for me because I want that the Chrome browser will stay open so I will be able to continue to work on the site from the place the automatic test finished.

The problem is, that when I am closing the chrome browser manually, the chromedriver.exe staying in the memory of the machine and not terminated so in the next test i will have another chromedriver.exe in the memory and so on.

Will be great if i can tell to the chromedriver.exe to terminate itself when the last chrome insistence will be closed. As i explained, i can not do it grammatically because the test method already ended.

I know that i can loop over all the process each time i am executing the test and kill any active webdriver process but i don't like that way.

Just to make things clear,  I want automation until a specific point and then to continue manually, after the automation part completed. On that point, i can not access the instance of the driver to use `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()` method. I am using Microsoft.NET TestMethod.

Comment: You want to close the browser *manually* when you run *autotests*? Why? If you don't want to re-open browser for each test-case then open it for test-run and call `driver.quit()` once the last test-case executed

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for the response. As i explained in my question. i want automation until a specific point and then to continue manually, after the automation part completed.

Comment: In this case it's not an *automated unit tests*. However you can use, for instance, in Python `input()` to wait for user input (like pressing Enter button) to continue to run script. Anyway, I'm sure that this is X-Y problem and you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: @Omtechguy You mentioned about _Microsoft.NET TestMethod_. Are you open to consider answers in other language bindings e.g _Java_ or _Python_?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Sure, thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your test script finishes - exits, and you continue using the browser for manual checks. So at the end (of the manual tests) you cannot close the driver processes programmatically - because you don't have a running program. In the same time, " i can loop over all the process each time i am executing the test and kill any active webdriver process but i don't like that way." - you don't want to do it as the first step of a future run. In that case - again, if I understood you - *when* do you want to do that? Considering you don't have a code of yours running...

Comment: @todor i want to unload chromewebdriver when i close the browser

Comment: That's given - the question is - how you want to do it? If you want to do it with some code, as I understand it you don't have any program of yours running. If I **have not** understand you correctly, and you have code that's running - then the question boils down to "How to kill a process in c# / vb.net / etc" - correct? Otherwise - if you want to end them manually, just open the task manager and kill the processes there.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- `driver.close()`: It is used to close the current page or the browser (if it is the only page/tab) which is having the focus.
- `driver.quit()` : It is used to call the /shutdown endpoint and subsequently the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* instances are destroyed gracefully closing all the pages/tabs/windows.
- You can find a detailed discussion in about the difference between `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
- Even after invoking `driver.quit()` if the *WebDriver* / *Web Browser* still stays in memory you can kill them with brute force following the discussion [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)
- Once your *Automated Tests* are completed to terminate only the *ChromeDriver* binary and keep the *Chrome Browser* stay open you can use use [Python raise Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_raise.asp) and you can use the following *(Python based)* solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import psutil

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  try:
      raise ValueError('Test Execution completed ... Killing the ChromeDriver instance only')
  except Exception as error:
      print('Caught this error: ' + repr(error))
      PROCNAME = "chromedriver.exe" # or geckodriver.exe or IEDriverServer.exe
      for proc in psutil.process_iter():
          # check whether the process name matches
          if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
              proc.kill()
  print("Only ChromeDriver instance was killed and Chrome Browser instance left open")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Caught this error: ValueError('Test Execution completed ... Killing the ChromeDriver instance only',)
  Only ChromeDriver instance was killed and Chrome Browser instance left open
  ```
- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: Why are you providing PhantomJS (no longer maintained and OP stated he's using chromedriver) and python code and links when OP clearly stated, "I am using Microsoft.NET"?

Comment: @JeffC Possibly you missed to check the related discussion just below the question as `@Omtechguy You mentioned about Microsoft.NET TestMethod. Are you open to consider answers in other language bindings e.g Java or Python?` and `@DebanjanB - Sure, thanks`. Moreover the answers within the discussion `PhantomJS web driver stays in memory` are generic and applies to all the _WebDriver_ variants

Comment: That's why the question should be updated with all the relevant data. PhantomJS is not the same as chromedriver though...

Comment: why do you raise an exception just to catch it?  totally unnecessary