# Mozilla FireFox (Not Responding) - Selenium WebDriver Refuses to die via driver.quit() command

Tags: java, windows, selenium, firefox, process

My program launches several dozen instances of `WebDriver` in parallel and kills them when certain conditions are met or when I manually terminate the program. At any given time I might have 4 dozen active `WebDriver` instances and to kill unwanted instances I call:

`driver.quit();`

If `driver.quit();` throws exception I kill `WebDriver` by PID via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec() taskkill` command.

Most of the active drivers are destroyed with this call (when I exit program). However, there's usually a handful (1-3) that 'hang' with the message `Mozilla FireFox (Not Responding)`. And they never die.

I'm unable to determine the root cause of the issue as the command I'm using to kill `WebDriver` is generally working. I've looked at several threads on SO regarding similar issues but I feel none of them address my problem because, as stated, the command I'm using works in general - it's just not working on all instances. As far as I see, there's is no difference between the way any of the drivers operate. Also, no error/exception is thrown when I call `driver.quit()`. So it seems purely random when the command works and doesn't work.

What might cause Firefox to hang like this and not respond to `quit()` command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but when certain conditions are met **don't** manually terminate the program instead use:

```
driver.quit();
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)

---

In case you need to kill the *Firefox* processes forcefully you can also use the `taskkill()` (windows) command through **`getRuntime().exec()`** as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe /T");
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

---

In case **Mozilla FireFox** *hangs* with the message **`Mozilla FireFox (Not Responding)`** effectively means that something stopped *Mozilla FireFox* processes.

---

### Solution

As per the article [Firefox is not responding](https://windowsreport.com/fix-firefox-stuck/) there are multiple approaches to solve this issue (Windows 10) as follows:

- Close *Mozilla FireFox* (if the classic way isn’t working, close the program through Task Manager)
- Restart your [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system.
- *Update the system graphics card drivers*: Firefox can run into issues due to outdated drivers for the graphics card. You need to make sure that your [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system runs on the latest driver updates.
- *Disable hardware acceleration from Firefox*: Hardware acceleration feature is also related to the graphics card. In some situations, depending on certain graphic card setups, Firefox might get into a freeze loop when hardware acceleration is in use. So, turn off this feature.

Comment: thanks for your response however I am already calling driver.quit() (when I wrote about manually terminating program it's just a signal to call driver.quit() so you can ignore that part) My issue is that while the majority of instances are destroyed after calling driver.quit there's always 1 or 2 that 'hang'. Manually closing instance via task manager defeats the entire purpose of automation. It's also not practical for me to 'babysit' the server 24/7 as dozens of instances are launched and destroyed every hour. Looking forward to your insight. Thanks!