# Python selenium - Multiprocessing - How to close browser for an allocated process?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know you can use `driver.quit()` and `driver.close()` but how to close nicely when executed multiple processes?

**IDEAS:**

- Use process ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to end the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) and *Web Browser* session graciously you should invoke the `quit()` method within the `tearDown() {}`. Invoking *quit()* deletes the current browsing session through sending `quit` command with `{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}` and finally sends the `GET` request on `/shutdown` endpoint. Here is the relevant log:

```
1503397488598   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/8e457516-3335-4d3b-9140-53fb52aa8b74 
1503397488607   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,4,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
1503397488821   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /shutdown
```

So on invoking `quit()` method the Web Browser session and the WebDriver instance gets killed completely.

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)
- [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)