# Selenium Edge- How to clear cache and close the restore pages popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, ui-automation

There are 2 issues here
1.Unable to clear cache and
2. the restore pop up comes up always when edge browser is launched.
Is there any edgeoption /capability available for this?

EdgeOptions Used:

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
capabilities.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", false);
        options.merge(capabilities);
        options.addArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
        options.addArguments("--disable-session-crashed-bubble");
        options.addArguments("--disable-application-cache");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

Currently using taskkill to close any existing browsers before opening the new edge browser for automation

```
 rt.exec("taskkill /im msedge.exe /f /t");
```

And for clearing the cache -> launching the clearBrowserData using the below

```
edge://settings/clearBrowserData
```

and clearing the cache

Comment: @YuZhou , currently I was doing the clear cache the same way you mentioned, but I was looking for edgeoption /capability that could help , same with restore pop up too. 
But yes, the method you mentioned for clearing cache works.

Comment: I didn't find edge options to achieve this. I'll continue to do research about this. Let's wait to see if there are other community members who have other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the page `edge://settings/clearBrowserData` to clear browsing data. Simulate clicking the **Clear now** button in the page to clear cache like this:

```
driver.get("edge://settings/clearBrowserData");
driver.findElement(By.id("clear-now")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

About the restore popup, have you close & destroy the WebDriver and Web Client instances properly? If you close them properly in your code, I think the restore popup won't show up. You need to use `driver.quit()` at the end of your code to make sure closing instances properly when you finish automating. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790) for more information.