# assert_process_still_running() and WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited error using SeleniumPython in Raspberry Pi

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am somewhat frustrated and have already completely reinstalled my Raspberry Pi because of this issue. I can't seem to get geckodriver to work. I get the following error message.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Geckodriver Version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ geckodriver -v
1645706311333   webdriver::httpapi      DEBUG   Creating routes
1645706311398   geckodriver     DEBUG   Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

PATH

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I updated raspian of course.

Thanks @undetected Selenium for your answer.

I tried the following with my test.py

```
import os
import psutil

PROCNAME = "geckodriver" # or chromedriver or IEDriverServer
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            print(PROCNAME)
            proc.kill()

from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I'm getting the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Do you guys know why, how can i fix this issue?

Thanks a lot!

#################
UPDATE

I tried the following code:

```
import os
import psutil

PROCNAME = "geckodriver" # or chromedriver or IEDriverServer
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            proc.kill()

from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The result is the same. Same error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error (same error except status code was -6), but in my case it was because I was using the deprecated browser driver initialization (directly giving executable path to webdriver instead of passing it a Service object).

Instead of:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

DRIVER="geckodriver"
service = Service(executable_path=DRIVER)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

See https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#4-hard-coded-location

Hope that might help you or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

...implies that there are [Zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) still occupying your system memory.

---

### Solution

Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) and *Web Client* instances gracefully to avoid the dangling process instances.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevent detailed discussions in:

- [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985790/7429447)
- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48003289/7429447)

Comment: I restarted my raspberry pi and I'm still getting this error. I would expect it to work at least on the first try after a reboot if a running service was the problem. Or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Do you see the same error?

Comment: Yes. I have added the error log as an answer above. Code was to long for comment.

Comment: I updated my post. Hope you can help me!