# Change of default directory path for rest_mozprofile from geckodriver

Tags: firefox, geckodriver

Geckodriver creates rust_mozprofile directory in '/tmp' directory.

There is a way to modify the path from '/tmp' to '/home' or some other location.

Could you please point me in right direction on how to do that.

Currently I am using

- Selenium - 3.3.0
- Firefox - 52.2.0
- Geckodriver - 13

Comment: I found this link - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#firefox-capabilities. But still can't able to fix it.

Comment: hey did you figure it out yet? I have the same question

Comment: I didn't get any solution but the problem which I had was memory issues. So I wrote a cron job to clean up whatever it is older.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()`

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit)

Another solution is to add a custom profile

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('specify location to profile .default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```