# Closing only 1 tab in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

So recently I have been using Selenium and Python to automate searches/go to websites. And so I looked up how to open new tabs in selenium because opening new windows every time for a search is a pain. I ended up using this code from a solution I found online

```
browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(2)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
browser.get("http://google.com")
```

to open a new tab. However the problem now arose that I need to close the tabs eventually. I tried using `browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')` to try to close the tab but that didn't work. I also tried to use `browser.close()` but that just closed the entire window and the rest of the code failed. Any ideas on how to close tabs?

Here is the full code

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession")

browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(2)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
browser.get("http://google.com")
searchh = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
text = "does CNN do newsletters?"

time.sleep(31)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: *"...but that just closed the entire window and the rest of the code failed"* How did you apply it? Show in your code

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you use `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()`

[Difference between webdriver.Dispose(), .Close() and .Quit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit)

Comment: Thanks for the help and the link to the post.