# Windows vs tabs in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

As per [Difference between webdriver.Dispose(), .Close() and .Quit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit)
`driver.close` closes the current active **window** where `driver.quit` closes all of the **windows**. What I get is if I opened a new tab in my current window and then called `driver.close` the whole windows including my tabs would close. But when I run that code

```
driver.get("http://testingpool.com/selenium-ide-part-1/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[8]/span/a")).click(); //opens a new tab
ArrayList<String> allWindowHandles = new ArrayList<> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.close()
```

only the first tabs gets closed. Also I find that my allWindowHandles has length of 2 although I have only one window.
I was trying to open a new window using Selenium as per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-open-a-new-window-on-a-browser-using-selenium-webdriver-for-python using

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('')");
```

but that resulted in a new tab not a new window.

I am confused if Selenium differentiates between a tab and a window at all or not.

Comment: tabs and windows in this context are the same thing.   there is no difference to Selenium at all.  The behavior of whether to open a new tab or new window is controlled by the browser.  (Used to be somewhat controlled by target... "_blank", "_parent", "_self"... but I think the browser preference now controls all of that behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the terminology used to distinguish between `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` methods supported by *Selenium WebDriver* in the [post you are referencing to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit), they actually mostly mean browser **tabs**, not **windows**.
By opening a new browser **window** with

```java
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('')");
```

or by clicking on some web element opening a new browser tab/window is will normally open a new **tab** in the existing browser.

Answer (score 1):

> What I get is if I opened a new tab in my current window and then
> called `driver.close` the whole window including my tabs would close.
> But when I run that code

See you may have opened a new tab **by clicking on link** or using `JavascriptExecutor` but Selenium still has focus on first tab of the first window.

Therefore, when you do this:

```
ArrayList<String> allWindowHandles = new ArrayList<> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.close()
```

It should close the `first tab` or `window`, since you have not switched to new tab/window.

> Also I find that my allWindowHandles has length of 2

this is cause you have opened a new tab using this line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[8]/span/a")).click(); //opens a new tab
```

the moment you open **a new tab by clicking on a link** or Using `JavascriptExecutor`, you will have `+1 windows handle`.

However, if you do not switch to any tab or window/s. Selenium will always have focus on first tab of the first window.

Also, `window.open('')` is Js command not Selenium.

there is a difference between a new tab or windows. But if you take Selenium into consideration, We switch to new tab or windows in a same way.

However to open a new window, you would have to simulate `CTRL+N` keyboard action.