# Selenium start chrome hidden C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want start Chrome hidden. I using Web Driver version 2.21.0.

I try this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
optionsChrome.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I have problem with `ChromeDriver(options);`

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property Form1.Options

If this possible I want start chrome totally hidden, how I can do that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium. You can't refer any fields in field initializer. Use constructor instead. Refer the duplicate question above your post.

Answer (score 1):

This may be able to help you in your search. It looks like it shows for Firefox more-so than Chrome, but it might help. [Can Selenium Webdriver open browser windows silently in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background)

This one looks closer to what you are looking for though [ChromeDriver console application hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501623/chromedriver-console-application-hide).

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/how-to-start-a-selenium2-webdriver-window-in-background