# Pyinstaller opens command prompt

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, exe, pyinstaller

I'm still a beginner with coding so maybe this question will be trivial for some of you. My apologies in advance.

For a project, i made a webcrawler using python and selenium, with an user interface made with Tkinter. I use a chromedriver to open chrome for the webcrawling part.

I converted my Tkinter file with pyinstaller into an executable file. When doing so, i typed the following flags: --onefile -w

I was told that the latter one prevents opening a command prompt when running the file, however, when i run the executable, my pc opens the command prompt for the chromedriver. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

-w will prevent the creation of a console for the main exe, not for the execution of the chromedriver.
You should have a look at [ChromeDriver console application hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501623/chromedriver-console-application-hide) thread for removing the console created by chromedriver

Comment: Yeah i was able to figure that out, but do you know how i can fix this? I searched on stackoverflow and some said to change things in service.py of the selenium package, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you have a look to the link I provided ? It seemed to me that it could help you

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the link you provided. They talk about C# and i dont know how to translate their solution to python code. I also tried this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python), but that didnt help. However, i wonder if i have to save things in a special way in order for selenium to use the modified service.py. I just saved it and run my main file. Can that be the problem?