# How to hide cmd window with python selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cmd, selenium-chromedriver

When I run my selenium application, a cmd window pops up, followed by a chrome window. I want to hide the cmd window. So far I have tried code from [this website](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007189411--Chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notification) and code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871898/how-to-hide-chromedriver-console-window?rq=1). None of them helped. I also found someone trying to do [this is C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501623/chromedriver-console-application-hide). He seemed to find a solution. Is there a way to do this in python with selenium chromedriver? Here is a picture of the cmd window:

[image: cmd window that pops up]

I also want to make it clear that the app runs completely fine with this window open. I just think the app would more usable without it.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.
Change a parameter value actually works for me.

Location: inside virtual environment `\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common`, find the `services.py` file.
Find the `start()` function, add parameter `creationflags=134217728`.

```
   self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                   close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                   stdout=self.log_file,
                                   stderr=self.log_file,
                                   stdin=PIPE,creationflags=134217728)
```

Comment: where did the value `134217728` come from?

Comment: 134217728 is actually from the subprocess module:  the numerical value of subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW